# .get () requires a callback function error in expressjs even though the syntax is correct

Tags: javascript, express, routes

I'm very new to expressjs and still learning. When I start the server it gives me the error - .get() requires callback function but got a [object undefined]. This error comes due to the following line but not sure why.

```
app.get('/about', routes.about);
```

The above line reside in app.js -

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/about', routes.about);
// app.get('/about', function(req, res) {
//   res.send('abcd');
// });
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);


http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

My about.js file is in the routes folder and the code is -

```
exports.about = function(req,res) {
    res.render('about', {body:'Welcome to my about section.'});
};
```

Not sure why the error when I tried confirming from a few places that this is how you define a route.

Comment: Seems like there is no `about.js` in your `./routes` folder

Comment: @antyrat - I do have about.js file in ./routes folder and I have pasted the code as well.

Answer (score 0):

I really tried this many times, but never found a solution.. so I use a workaround.
But if anybody know how to use the "routes system" please tell me :)

In your case it would look like this:

```
app.get('/about', function(req,res){
    res.render('about', {body:'Welcome to my about section'});
});
```

Marvin

Comment: That's the exact same thing that I wrote except for the part that I put the 
`function(req,res){
    res.render('about', {body:'Welcome to my about section'});
}` 
in a new `about.js` file in my routes and I'm trying to call that using `routes.about` in the `app.get('/about', routes.about);` function.

Comment: Yes i know, but please give it a try.. because if you use the code snippet, I posted ,in your app.js it should work. In my opinion the isn't the `app.get` function, it's the route which doesn't work.

Comment: That's the thing, I wanted to know why isn't the route working. If you look closely at the code I provided, I have already commented out the solution that you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like express is working fine, but how you are loading your modules is wrong. By looking at these lines:

```
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
```

I can assume that `'./routes'` is a folder. You are setting `var routes` equal to a folder? I have no idea what your directory looks like, but you said your about function was in `about.js`. So your code should be as follows

`var routes = require('./routes/about')`

and that's assuming that your `routes` folder is on the same level as this server file, otherwise you'd have to require in the right path. That should solve it.